# macOS Sierra - iMessage corrects me despite spellcheck is turned off

Tags: macos, messages, spellcheck

Good day!
iMessage on my mac fixes my typos as I type despite the fact that I've disabled spell check in settings.

Here is how it looks:

[image: iMessage]

[image: Preferences]

Is there any way to fix that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not actually fixing anything, just telling you it doesn't recognise the word. If it had fixed it, the word would be a) spelled correctly & b) underlined in blue dots, not red.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but how do I show you fixing as I type unless I do some sort of a screencap? See answer to my question below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Messages, go to Edit > Spelling and Grammar and make sure the items for automatic correction are UNchecked.

Comment: also completely quit the Messages app after changing the settings, then restart it.

Comment: Wow, they should really use the global settings under System Pref > Keyboard. I foresee more idiosyncrasies like this as they move more phone apps in to osx ‍♂️

Comment: @IvanAracki  You missed the point.  In Catalina, just like earlier MacOS versions, the setting is in BOTH places, and you may have to check both of them to get the result you want.

Comment: Also accessible in the context menu by right clicking the text field